# Could anyone please explain how to use postcss-preset-env's importFrom?

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, css-variables

I'm trying to use Webpack+PostCSS. Here's the CSS config:

```
const cssRule = {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        {loader: 'css-loader'},
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                plugins: [
                    postcssImport({
                        paths: ['./assets']
                    }),
                    postcssPresetEnv({
                        stage: 0,
                        browsers: 'Firefox ESR',
                        importFrom: ['./assets/shared/colors.css']
                    }),
                    postcssEasingGradients()
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The assets/shared/colors.css file looks like this:

```
:root {
    --color-primary-0: #051845;
    --color-primary-1: #05112B;
    --color-primary-2: #041335;
    --color-primary-3: #092568;
    --color-primary-4: #0A328D;

    --color-primary-3-a20: #09256820;

    --color-secondary-1-0: #200446;
    --color-secondary-1-1: #16052C;
    --color-secondary-1-2: #190336;
    --color-secondary-1-3: #310769;
    --color-secondary-1-4: #42098F;

    --color-secondary-2-0: #004628;
    --color-secondary-2-1: #012C1A;
    --color-secondary-2-2: #00361F;
    --color-secondary-2-3: #006A3D;
    --color-secondary-2-4: #009153;

    --light-gray: #EEE;
    --dark-gray: #333;
}
```

But when I try using this colors, Firefox devtools complain that the variables are unset, and the actual colors are nowhere to be seen.

What am I doing wrong?

---

P. S. I also tried similar setup with Webpack css-loader's import, with exact same results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## Update
>
> Consider my later, simpler, more up-to-date answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67610503/11817077

## Answers

> **What am I doing wrong?**

There may not be a single answer. Try these.

**A. You are not [exporting the variables](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env/issues/141#issuecomment-511242094).** I suggest trying to import the variables you want to use, then export the variables. "Why export what you already have to import?!" I still ask myself this, but I have made progress by believing the following *assumption*:

> Based on my understanding, importing is for `postcss-preset-env` to apply static replacements and track where it cannot make a static replacement, while exporting is for `postcss-preset-env` to output variables that are necessary in the CSS for dynamic CSS behavior.

**B. Set the [`postcss-preset-env` option `preserve`](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env#preserve) to `true`.** Doing so *should* tell plugins to include "pre-polyfilled" CSS (like your missing variables). I have an *opinion* against this:

> Based on my understanding, the `exportTo` option allows `postcss-preset-env` to "pre-polyfill" the CSS, in order to improve performance of bundled CSS, while the `preserve`-set-to-`false` option provides all variables in the bundled CSS.

**C. Evaluate whether Webpack has unexpected behavior.** [Parcel 1.0 parses each CSS file independently, when bundling](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1165#issuecomment-380150076). Without a bundler (no Webpack, Parcel, Rollup, etc), I compiled functional code by **both** setting `preserve` to `false` **and** *not* using `exportTo`. See "Warning" section.

> **Could anyone please explain how to use postcss-preset-env's importFrom?**

**Maybe.** You seem to be using `importFrom` correctly. But, you can try these steps for any of the above answers.

**Answer A**

1. Provide, via [`importFrom`](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env#importfrom), the variables that you want available to `postcss-preset-env` (while it parses your CSS).
2. Define, via [`exportTo`](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env#exportto), where to create a CSS file that you want to be included in your final CSS.
3. Include the exported CSS in the final CSS.

**Answer B**

1. Test whether setting `postcss-preset-env` option `preserve` to `false` or `true` resolves the issue.

**Answer C**

1. Test PostCSS independently of Webpack. I recommend [`postcss-cli`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli).

## Warning

The success rate of `postcss-preset-env`, using the imported variables and deciding the variables necessary to export, is dependent on:

- the **format** of the **values** passed to `importFrom` and `exportTo`

  - path(s) to files with data
  - direct data input
- the **format** of the **variables** passed to `importFrom` and `exportTo`

  - CSS
  - JSON
  - JavaScript object
- the **order** in which the **values**/**variables** are passed

The [plugin test cases](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env/tree/master/test) do **not** test order from files; the [`import`
test](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env/blob/master/.tape.js#L129) tests only a single order from simple objects with basic usage.

The details of the order elude me. More complex test cases may be required.

### My Experience Using [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) (Not Webpack)

Different loader, but same plugin.

1. If the format of these variable sources are file paths in an array, then *order matters*:

   - custom selectors
   - environmental variables
2. Placing either of *those two* variable source first will make the other ineffectual.
3. If *those two* variable source formats are *one* JavaScript object **and** *one* file path, then *order matters*.
4. If *those two* variable source formats are **both** JavaScript objects, then *order does **not** matter*.
5. The order of *other* variable sources, if from files, seems irrelevant.

## Reference

1. [`postcss-preset-env` Issue #141: "Confused about `importFrom` and the expected output"](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env/issues/141)
2. Personal trial and error, and some systematic testing.
3. The `postcss-preset-env` test cases do not cover the examples shown in the documentation.
4. *Reading my pulled-out clumps of hair as if they are oracle bones.*

Answer (score 1):

> This is a newer, different, more up-to-date answer than my old one.

Ensure that `importFrom` is set *within the options for the specific feature plugin*, **not** within the `postcssPresetEnv` options.

See [csstools/postcss-preset-env#202](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env/issues/202) "Able to export custom-media but not custom-properties".

Answer (score 1):

`importFrom` and `exportTo` will be deprecated - https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/discussions/192

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32409886)